# How to mail to bunch of mail id in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

Hi i have been developing simple school project, in that i want send the mail to startmark entry if the enrolments of the student get completed.

i have tables

allotment

```
*section_id
*user_id
```

user

```
*user_id
*email
```

enrolment controller

```
def update
unless params[:students] && params[:section_id] && !params[:is_academic].nil?
  send_back GlobalUtils.false_response_hash and return
end

section = Section.find( params[:section_id] )
Mailers.mark_entry_notification(section).deliver
send_back( response_hash, :scope_3 )
end


mailers.rb

def mark_entry_notification(section)  
section_id = section.id
array_user_id=[]
Allotment.each do |allot|
  array_user_id << allot.user_id.where(allot.section_id = section_id)
end
array_user_mail=[]
User.each do |usr|
  array_user_mail << usr.user_email.where(usr.user_id = array_user_id)
end
mail(:to => "array_user_mail" :subject => student enrollment is completed  )
end
```

is this correct? is that will send a mail?

Comment: Use delayed job for this process, and you can use 3rd party Email services like Mailgun

Comment: Iam using delayjob.Any error in the coding? i want know whether  array_user_mail << usr.user_email.where(usr.user_id = array_user_id) will work? is there any alternative

Comment: The code within mailer.rb will not work at all. I could'nt understand the code. How do you want to collect your Users to send mail. Let me try to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you expect:

In enrolment controller,

```
def update
    unless params[:students] && params[:section_id] && !params[:is_academic].nil?
      send_back GlobalUtils.false_response_hash and return
    end

    Mailers.mark_entry_notification(params[:section_id]).deliver
    send_back( response_hash, :scope_3 )
end
```

in mailers.rb,

```
def mark_entry_notification(section_id)  
    array_user_ids = array_user_emails = [] 
    array_user_ids = Allotment.where(:section_id=>section_id).pluck(:user_id)   
    array_user_emails = User.where(:id=>array_user_ids).pluck(:user_email)
    mail(:to => array_user_emails, :subject => "Student enrollment is completed" )
end
```

Hope this helps you.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

mail(:to => **array_user_mail** :subject => student enrollment is completed)

Note down the bolded text. Need not to use quotes for a ruby variable. You can send mails to multiple users in this way.

I wonder why you have written this many lines of code just to fetch the email ids of User model.

```
array_user_mail = User.pluck(:user_email)
```

if you are using lower version of rails, try the following

```
array_user_mail = User.map(&:user_email)
```

Also, Are you sure the following code works in your application?

```
 array_user_id << allot.user_id.where(allot.section_id = section_id)
```

You are trying to use where condition for table attribute. It is not possible right.?

Okay, Anyhow answering your actual question "Use **array_user_mail** without quotes in :to"

assuming **array_user_mail** is a proper array.. He he he... Kidding!!

Comment: I used that because i dont want the email ids of entire model, just to  the user mails of the user to whom the user id matches to found user_id's